# Execute mysql command before test script on GitLab CI

Tags: mysql, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to create the test database before my test script executes. I have included the mysql service, but I can't find a way to run mysql command.

I run `mysql ...` in `before-script`, but it keep complaining

```
/bin/bash: line 57: mysql: command not found
```

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`↓

```
image: maven:3.5-jdk-8

services:
  - mysql

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test-compile'

verify:
  stage: test
  before_script: 
    - mysql --user=root --password=\"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\" --host=mysql < src/main/sql/database.sql
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS verify'
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - target/*.jar
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are running MySQL in a different container as a service to connect to. The `maven:3.5-jdk-8` image doesn't contain the `mysql-client` package you invoke using `mysql`.

So to solve it; install the `mysql-client` in your before command:

```
before_script: 
    - apt-get update -q && apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends mysql-client
    - mysql --user=root --password=\"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\" --host=mysql < src/main/sql/database.sql
```