# Setting up CI/CD on Gitlab for django project

Tags: django, gitlab

This is the first time I've tried adding CI/CD for a Django project on gitlab. I want to set up automatic testing and deploying to the server in the development branch if it is successful.
With tests almost everything worked out, dependencies are installed and started `python manage.py test` but the problem with the testing database. The traceback error is a bit lower and here I don't quite understand how the interaction with the database happens during the tests.

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
 .....
 MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)")
 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
     main()
   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
...
     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
 django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)")
```

In the settings of django `settings.py`, a connector to the database is obtained through such variables in a .env file.

**.env**

```
SECRET_KEY=ja-t8ihm#h68rtytii5vw67*o8=o)=tmojpov)9)^$h%9#16v&
DEBUG=True
DB_NAME=db_name
DB_USER=username
DB_PASSWORD=dbpass
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

And with the deployment of the project, everything is not clear yet. I'd appreciate your help setting it up.

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - apt update -qy
  - apt install python3 python3-pip virtualenvwrapper -qy
  - virtualenv --python=python3 venv/
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - python manage.py test 

stage: deploy
  script:
  ...
  ???
  only:
  - develop
```

**UPD**
Accordingly Ruddra recommendation I added to yml file next line:

```
services:
- mysql

variables:
  # Configure mysql service (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_DATABASE: test
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql

connect:
  image: mysql
  script:
  - echo "SELECT 'OK';" | mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql "$MYSQL_DATABASE"
```

And as a result I got **connect** successful status and **test** error 
status with the same traceback as a starting question

Comment: You're trying to connect to your localhost database. You need to set up a database for your production environment and make a separate set of environment variables that are read only on production

Comment: @Snackoverflow would you help me with this?

Comment: Where do you deploy to?

Comment: I deploy at AWS

Comment: Check https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-mysql-db/ to see how to setup a database in AWS. Check this to find more about how to load environment variables on production only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664244/django-how-to-manage-development-and-production-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can run [**`MySQL`**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/mysql.html) as service in GitLab. For example:

```
services:
  - mysql:latest

variables:
  # Configure mysql environment variables (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_DATABASE: "db_name"
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "dbpass"
  MYSQL_USER: "username"
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: "dbpass"
```

**Update:** In your `.env` file, update the following settings:

```
DB_HOST=mysql
```

**Update 2:** (Based on this issue on [**`GitLab`**](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3042)) You can update the code like this:

```
variables:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "db_name"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "dbpass"
      MYSQL_USER: "username"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "dbpass"

test:
  script:
    - apt update -qy
    - mysql --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASSWORD --database=$MYSQL_DATABASE --host=$MYSQL_HOST --execute="SHOW DATABASES; ALTER USER '$MYSQL_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '$MYSQL_PASSWORD'"
```

Comment: I got `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, 'Plugin sha256_password could not be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb19/plugin/sha256_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory')`

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50014173/2696165

Comment: Yes this link is usefull. I changed to - `mysql:5.7` but unfortunately there is now an access error.  `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'userlocal'@'172.17.0.3' (using password: YES)")`

Comment: @Jekson also you can look into Update2 section of the answer :)

Comment: I'll try your second  advice

Comment: `/bin/bash: line 95: mysql: command not found` . Wrong sintax?

Comment: Again, please see the updated answer. (based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46873279/2696165)

Comment: Why is it so complicated! Now I get  `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: Okay, then just use `script` for that. Please see the updated answer

Comment: With `script` the result is the same.

Comment: I will mark that the answer is correct, because in principle the current problem is another question. And just create a new question by the database connection error.